# How can I use the same path on a Mac and PC?

Tags: windows, macos, unc

I have an application (Lightroom specifically), in which I want to work on a Mac or PC and access the files using the same path. This is the only way I can think to make the transition back and forth seamless.

For example, I want a path like this:

```
smb://server/path
```

or like this:

```
\\server\path
```

but in a format that is common to both.

I suspect that the Mac is more flexible, and has a way of mounting a drive and adding an alias that matches the UNC format on a PC.

Comment: Makes you wonder why there isn't anything for Windows yet that supports the `smb:` scheme...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Does anything on Windows support the cifs:// scheme? Because Mac OS X treats it as synonymous with smb:// as far as I know.